# Вложенный try-catch и возврат ошибок

Tags: c#

В программе обрабатывается массив записей из базы данных с помощью цикла `foreach`. Для каждой записи происходит формирование класса запроса и потом отправка этого запроса на сервис. При возникновении ошибки при обращении к сервису (например сервис не доступен или превышено время ожидания) нужно перейти к следующей записи, и попробовать обработать текущую запись в следующий раз. Если ошибка возникла при формировании класса запроса мне необходимо присвоить данной записи из бд статус ошибочной и закрыть ее. Решение вижу следующим образом

```
foreach (var item in collection)
{
    switch (code)
    {
        case 1:
            try
            {
                //формируем класс зпроса 
                try
                {
                    //отправляем запрос на сервис
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //возникла ошибка обращения к сервису  
                    //переходим к след итерации цикла
                    continue;
                    //throw;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //"закрываем" данную запись 
                //throw;
            }

            break;
        //...
    }
}
```

Но сомневаюсь как вложенность `try-catch` скажется на производительности (по сути в каждом `case` будет данная конструкция), возможно есть более правильное решение?

Comment: во всех кейсах будет такая же конструкция?

Comment: @Ep1demic, да , но логика формирования запроса и сервисы разные

Comment: А зачем вложенность? Ведь можно задать под каждую ошибку свой `catch` и там уже делайте что надо при ошибке. Заверните сам  `switch` в `try/catch` и в конце пишите все ошибки и действия. Почитайте [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) для лучшего представления.

Answer (score 3):

А как на счет того, чтобы сделать это следующим образом?

Первое - поменять *switch* по *int* на более понятный **Enum**.

Второе - создать статический (а возможно и нет...) класс, который будет создавать запросы и отправлять их на сервер, например **RequestHandler**:

```
class RequestHandler{

    public static Request makeRequest(EnumValue){
        /**
         * Перенести switch сюда.
         * В каждом case выбрасывать кастомную ошибку "на верх" из этого метода.
         * Например, throw new MakeRequestException();
         */
    }    

    public static void sendRequest(Request request){
        /**
        * Посылаем нужный запрос.
        * Если возникает ошибка - по аналогии прокидываем ее "на верх".
        * Например, throw new SendRequestException()
        */
    }
}
```

Далее уже Ваш код приобретет более "понятный" вид:

```
foreach(var item in collection){
    try{
        var request = RequestHandler.makeRequest(item.code);
        RequestHandler.sendRequest(request);
    } catch (MakeRequestException ex) {
       //"закрываем" данную запись 
    } catch (SendRequestException ex) {
       continue;
    }
}
```

Еще более логичным, правильным было бы вынести метод *sendRequest* в класс **Request**

Что даст такое разбиение кода?

1. Уменьшение кода (не нужно будет писать под каждый кейс одинаковый `try/catch`
2. Более удобная читаемость кода (каждое действие разбито на логические единицы (методы и классы), *switch* внутри не по абстрактным единицам-ноликам, а со вполне логическими названиями.

Answer (score 1):

Если вы работаете с внешними сервисами (как база данных в вашем случае), то это будет самим медленным местом вашего приложения. Скорость выполнения `try-catch` инструкций будет на порядки ниже, и вам не стоит беспокоится об этом.

Вложенность `try-catch` никак не влияет на производительность, самая медленная операция - это вброс исключения, и она не зависит от вложенности блоков.

Беспокоится о производительности `try-catch` стоит только тогда, когда вы собираетесь вбрасывать миллионы исключений в секунду.

А по вашему коду, не совсем понятно, зачем вам вложенность. Почему не сделать так:

```
try {
    //формируем класс зпроса
}
catch {
    //"закрываем" данную запись;
    continue;
}

try {
    //отправляем запрос на сервис
}
catch { continue; }
```

Comment: Стоит еще заметить, что обрабатывать **все** исключения в одном блоке catch - не очень хорошая практика. Есть исключения, при которых можно продолжить работать, есть такие, при которых нужно делать дополнительный запрос. А есть такие, при которых лучше аварийно завершить работу приложения.

Comment: @MikhailEfremov да, это верно. Мой код просто наброска. Главный посыл в том, что можно сделать то же самое без вложенных `try-catch`.